# Which stories to believe?

Tags: shiva, other-religions, dayananda-saraswati

there are have been stories of people claiming that shiv ji or krishna came to help them,
they themselves seeing them in their form. But there is also story of dayanand that god is formless(he saw a mouse on a shivling and doubted the existence of god ). Which stories to believe?
For instance we can take the cases of other religion too they say god comes in this from to protect?Whom to believe?

Comment: Dayananda Saraswati's assumptions are erroneous because 1) He accepts only the Vaidika Samhitas to be divinely inspired & completely rejects the Brahmanas, Aranyakas, Upanishadas, Parisisthas & Sutras as fabrications. 2) He completely cancelled the works of his predecessors like Sayana, Mahidhara & Halayudha on the grounds that they engaged in so-called 'idolatry'. 3)The Vaidika corpus available to us is fragmentary. Charanavyuha (a parisistha of Atharvaveda) lists the various reccessions of the Vedas, out of which only a handful is available to us, from which Dayananda drew his conclusions.

Comment: 4) In order to refute the opponent, one must be well acquianted with the opponent's viewpoint. For example, Kumarila Bhatta was able to almost single-handedly wipe out Madhayamaka Buddhism out of India because he was thoroughly acquianted with their views. However in case of Dayananda, it seems that he was hardly versed with the Hindu texts he refuted. His polemics against 'idolatry' was in tune with that raised by Muslims, Christians & Sikhs & his views on the Vedas sounded similar to the 'sola scriptura' doctrine of Protestantism.